# XSLT running in anypoint studio but not running in CloudHub

Tags: xml, xslt, mule, mule-studio, cloudhub

Hi am using an xslt transformer and using an xsl file am using a function ex:date-time() its running in Anypoint studio but when I try to run in cloudHub its throwing an error
**Cannot find a matching 0-argument function named {http://exslt.org/dates-and-times}date-time(). There is no Saxon extension function with the local name date-time (net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException)**

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 exclude-result-prefixes="xs ">
 <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="var1" select="." />
  <_ord:testOrder 
   xmlns:ex="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" extension-element-prefixes="ex"
  
   <xsl:attribute name="xsi:schemaLocation"
    namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:value-of select="test" />
   </xsl:attribute>
   <_wcf:ApplicationArea>
   <_oa:CreationDateTime><xsl:value-of select="ex:date-time()"/></_oa:CreationDateTime>
   
   </_wcf:ApplicationArea>
   
          </_ord:testOrder>
   
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Apparently Anypoint studio supports EXSLT, but Cloudhub doesn't. If you show the code, perhaps there is a workaround that does not use this function?

Comment: Hi Mathias added xslt code above

Comment: Is there any way i can add any EXSLT jar in cloudhub

Comment: The exception named `net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException` suggests that Saxon 8 or 9 is being used. In that case consider to simply write XSLT 2.0 with its built-in support for `xs:date` and `xs:dateTime` data types and functions like http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-current-dateTime instead of trying to use XSLT 1.0 with poorly support EXSLT extensions.

Comment: Consider testing your app on Mule Standalone locally on your machine: it should fail the same way as in CloudHub, thus making it easier for you to look for a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need separate license to use these functions.I think you are using HE of Saxon.Get Enterprise Edition of Saxon

Comment: Thanks I got that.I used java to overcome this issue

Answer (score 1):

CloudHub tends to use the lastest and greatest version of Mule. In 3.6 a [huge overhaul](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/mule-3-6-xml-xpath-xslt-xquery3/) of the XML dependencies have been done.

My guess is that you are probably testing localy against 3.5 and then running in cloudhub against 3.6. Please try setting your cloudhub configuration to use 3.5.

Comment: In cloudhub am working in dev environment and its using saxon HE so exslt are not supporting

Answer (score 0):

when referring xsl file via xslt transformer, it takes the full path of the xsl file, 
so i suspect the path was not modified so while deploying the project to cloudhub it was executing.

so after referring the xsl file via xslt transformer modify the path considering resource folder as root.

Comment: Its taking the file but the problem is exslt functions not working